# What's the most recent data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I have just discovered the filed of data structure and I am fascinated by it. IS there an encyclopedia of data structures? Or at least do you know any recently constructed data structure that is not yet popular?

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. Not remembering a collection of *data structures* intended to be comprehensive or encyclopaedic, or *recency* as a differentiator. Do you happen to know [wikiversity](https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Data_structures)?

Comment: You could try browsing the list of accepted papers at top conferences that include data structures, or you could have a look at recent preprints on arXiv.

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question in the body.  Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: New data structures are invited every day (or rather, pretty often). Most of them are of pure theoretical interest, but some may get actual use. Which are you interested in?